# Looping through a RefCell wrapped Vec with Rust

Tags: vector, iterator, rust

I have a struct that contains a `RefCell` for storing mutable values within a vector, and I'd like to loop over its values.

Adding an element causes no problems, but when attempting to convert the borrowed vector into an iterator it throws:

> error: cannot move out of borrowed content [E0507]

Why does the borrow even matter, if it's immutable? I don't understand why the compiler would mark this as a potential issue when the content of the variable doesn't even change.

I can get around the ownership issue by cloning it, but *why do I need to do that in the first place*? Cloning the structure I'm trying to loop over is probably going to have a high CPU cost and I'd prefer not to have to do it if possible.

Example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
fn main() {
    use std::cell::RefCell;
    let c = RefCell::new(vec![1, 2, 3]);

    let arr = c.borrow();

    for i in arr.into_iter() {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing here or is Rust being overly cautious about this?

Would appreciate it if someone could fill any gaps in my understanding of how this works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears the issue was in there being a difference between `Vec.into_iter` and `Vec.iter`. To solve, change:

```
for i in arr.into_iter() {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

to:

```
for i in arr.iter() {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

As described in [*Effectively Using Iterators In Rust*](http://hermanradtke.com/2015/06/22/effectively-using-iterators-in-rust.html).

Comment: Yes. As you can see here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html

`into_iter` is taking `self` (not &self, or &mut self), which means it is consuming (moving) the object it is being called on.

You can accept your own answer and close the question this way.