# Share Arc between closures

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a simple tcp server which would read and broadcast messages.
I'm using Tokio, but I think it's more of a general Rust question.

I have an Arc with a shared state:
`let state = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Shared::new(server_tx)));`

Later I want to spawn 2 threads which would use a reference to that state:

```
let server = listener.incoming().for_each(move |socket| {
    // error[E0382]: capture of moved value: `state`
    process(socket, state.clone());
    Ok(())
}).map_err(|err| {
    println!("accept error = {:?}", err);
});

let receive_sensor_messages = sensors_rx.for_each(move |line| {
    println!("Received sensor message, broadcasting: {:?}", line);

    // error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
    // error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content 
    for (_, tx) in state.clone().lock().unwrap().clients {
        tx.unbounded_send(line.clone()).unwrap();
    }
    Ok(())
}).map_err(|err| {
    println!("line reading error = {:?}", err);
});
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2100d6844c06e91c01e152db2b636fe9&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

As far as I understand what it's trying to tell me is that `state` is borrowed in the first closure `listener.incoming().for_each(move |socket| {` so when I try to do it again in `sensors_rx.for_each(move |line| {` it's saying it's not possible.

My question is how do I solve it? Isn't `Arc` supposed to solve the issue of sharing a variable between threads?
I tried different combinations of `clone` (doing clone outside of the closure and then doing `clone` inside again), but none worked.

Cheers!

Comment: Can you try to provide a MCVE instead of a full-blown program?

Comment: The "cannot move out of borrowed content" happens because a `for` loop consumes its argument (see, for example, [Looping through a RefCell wrapped Vec with Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820764/looping-through-a-refcell-wrapped-vec-with-rust)). Changing that line to `for (_, tx) in &state.lock().unwrap().clients` reduces your problem to the `Arc` issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Essentially, your problem can be boiled down [to the following MCVE:](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=a7103fe508a732f56c912b394426a3c4)

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

struct Bar;

fn foo(_ : &Bar){
    println!("foo called");
}

fn main(){
    let example = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Bar));
    std::thread::spawn(move ||{
        let _ = example.clone();
    });
    // --- (1) ---

    std::thread::spawn(move ||{
        foo(&example.clone().lock().unwrap());
    });
}
```

Now, the first problem here is that `example` is moved. That is, as soon as we crossed `(1)`, the original `example` is considered to be moved from. Instead, we need to *first* `clone` and *then* `move`:

```
    let example = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Bar));
    let local_state = example.clone();
    std::thread::spawn(move ||{
        let _ = local_state; // now fine!
    });
```

The other error stems from the short lived `Arc`. Essentially, it only lives long enough for you to us `lock` on the underlying `Mutex`. While *we* know that there is at least one other `Arc` pointing to the memory, the compiler cannot prove that. However, if we get rid of the `clone()` it's fine:

```
    let local_state = example.clone();        
    std::thread::spawn(move ||{
        foo(&local_state.lock().unwrap());
    });
```

However, you also loop over your container by consuming its contents (the `clients`). Instead, use `&` there, e.g. `&local_state().unwrap().clients`).

You can find the complete fixed code below [or on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=9ead81d80700d1b97d6cdfff9331d632):

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

struct Bar;

fn foo(_ : &Bar){
    println!("foo called");
}

fn main(){
    let example = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Bar));
    let local_state = example.clone();
    std::thread::spawn(move ||{
        let _ = local_state;
    });
    let local_state = example.clone();
    std::thread::spawn(move ||{
        foo(&local_state.lock().unwrap());
    }).join();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For every closure you have to provide its own `Arc`, so you have to `clone` your `Arc` beforehand.

```
let state = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Shared::new(server_tx)));
let state1 = Arc::clone(&state);
let state2 = Arc::clone(&state);

let server = listener.incoming().for_each(move |socket| {
    process(socket, state1.clone());
    Ok(())
});

let receive_sensor_messages = sensors_rx.for_each(move |line| {
    println!("Received sensor message, broadcasting: {:?}", line);
    let shared = state2.lock().unwrap();
    for (_, tx) in &shared.clients { // better: `for tx in shared.clients.values()`
        tx.unbounded_send(line.clone()).unwrap();
    }
    Ok(())
});
```

You could omit `state1` here, but I find it cleaner to do it like this.

The reason for this is, that you move in the value `state` into the first closure, so you cannot use it in the second closure, because it is already moved (makes sense, doesn't it?).