# Why does capturing an Arc by move make my closure FnOnce not Fn

Tags: rust, closures

In the below example, I'm using an Arc to reference server state from a request handler, but the compiler make the closure an `FnOnce`. It feels like I'm doing the right thing in that each closure owns a strong reference to the state. Why doesn't this work? What options are there to make it work? Other questions like [Share Arc between closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53045522/share-arc-between-closures) indicate something like this working, but I'm making the per-closure clones as shown and still getting an error.

```rust
#![feature(async_closure)]

#[derive(Default, Debug)]
struct State {}

impl State {
    pub async fn exists(&self, key: &str) -> bool {
        true
    }

    pub async fn update(&self, key: &str) {}
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    use warp::Filter;
    use std::sync::Arc;

    let state: Arc<State> = Arc::default();

    let api = warp::post()
        .and(warp::path("/api"))
        .and(warp::path::param::<String>().and_then({
            let state = Arc::clone(&state);
            async move |p: String| {
                let x = state.exists(&p);
                if x.await {
                    Ok(p)
                } else {
                    Err(warp::reject::not_found())
                }
            }
        }))
        .and_then({
            let state = Arc::clone(&state);
            async move |id: String| {
                state.update(&id).await;
                Result::<String, warp::Rejection>::Ok("".to_owned())
            }
        });

    warp::serve(api).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 0)).await;
}
```

```
error[E0525]: expected a closure that implements the `Fn` trait, but this closure only implements `FnOnce`
  --> src/main.rs:25:13
   |
23 |           .and(warp::path::param::<String>().and_then({
   |                                              -------- the requirement to implement `Fn` derives from here
24 |               let state = Arc::clone(&state);
25 |               async move |p: String| {
   |  _____________^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^_-
   | |             |
   | |             this closure implements `FnOnce`, not `Fn`
26 | |                 let x = state.exists(&p);
27 | |                 if x.await {
28 | |                     Ok(p)
...  |
31 | |                 }
32 | |             }
   | |_____________- closure is `FnOnce` because it moves the variable `state` out of its environment
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, async closures are unstable, so that may be a bug. I think that when the async block captures the `Arc` it consumes it, so the closure can actually only be called once. I mean, an async closure is some kind of generator: each time you call it it constructs a future, and it is the future which keeps the captured values.

As a workaround you may write something like this:

```
let state = Arc::clone(&state);
move |p: String| {
    let state = Arc::clone(&state);
    async move {
        let x = state.exists(&p);
        //...
    }
}
```

Doing another clone inside the closure but before the `async` block ensures that you can call the closure as many times as you need.

I would argue that actually `Warp::Filter` should accept a `FnOnce` to begin with, but I don't know `warp` enough to be sure.

Comment: "I would argue that actually Warp::Filter should accept a FnOnce to begin with, but I don't know warp enough to be sure." – The filters are called for each request that matches, so from my understanding I don't think `FnOnce` would be enough.

Comment: @devnev: Ah, because you are building a server, of course! I saw the `post` and assumed is was client code.